# proof using mathematical induction the largest anti-symmetric binary relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Using mathematical induction prove that, for a finite set $S$, the largest anti-symmetric binary relation $\rho\subseteq S\times S$ is such that:

$$|\rho| = \frac{|S|(|S|+1)}{2}$$

I tried solving this problem but I couldn't reach an answer. I hope someone could help.

Comment: Thanks for your post. For future reference, please use the link to format your questions: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Are you required to use induction? The result can be proved fairly easily without it.

Comment: yes I have to @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @mariamessam: That’s too bad (and in my opinion an example of inferior teaching), since (a) it’s an artificial limitation, and (b) another approach is actually a little more informative. Okay; **Agniv**’s answer below is a bit hard to follow, but the first paragraph is pretty much what you’re supposed to do.

Comment: Thank you @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @ReemTantawy: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

For one element set, size of such relation is 1, namely the only reflexive element so the result holds true.
Suppose for n element set, size of such relation is A =n(n+1)/2
Now for n+1 element set, size of such relation would be A +{1 element for (p,p) if p is the n+1 th element } + { n elements in the form (i, p) where i are previous n elements}. Note that (p,i) is not a part of the relation if (p,i) is, as the relationship is anti symmetric. So adding them all we get (n+1)((n+1)+1)/2.
Hence proved for all n.

Using combinatorics, the size of the relation will be {n for all the reflective tuples} + {half of  n choose 2 for all the other pairs counting only once occurance of (a,b) and (b,a) where a is not equal to b as the relation is anti symmetric.}